# Auto-hide enabled taskbar appears behind windows

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, window

I have auto-hide enabled for the taskbar. For some reason, it appears *behind* the windows, making it absolutely useless. Does anybody know of a fix for this?

Comment: Also enable always-on-top.

Comment: Does this happen when that option is disabled?

Comment: As far as I can see, there's no always-on-top option in Windows 10 for the taskbar. Also, this turned out to be a bug, not a wrong setting. See my own answer below.

Comment: @LPChip You're thinking about Task Manager.

Comment: @DonnyV No I'm not. Task bar (where all programs are that are running and allow you to switch to it) has a feature called Always On Top. If this is not enabled, the taskbar will go behind programs. Its just a setting that can be turned on or off because some programs running full-screen don't get above the taskbar, giving a weird taskbar. At least this once was the case, so for legacy reasons, taskbar can be set to not always be on top.

Comment: @LPChip The "Always on Top" feature was removed in Win7

Comment: @DonnyV Ah right... I use Actual Tools Window Manager and it can still control the always on-top feature of the taskbar. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting the computer. It happens to me after a long session or weeks without shutting down. But after a quick restart everything works fine.

Comment: I shut my PC completely down each night, so that's not it.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly enough I fixed it by unpinning a pinned app from the taskbar. Repinning it had no adverse effect.

Credit to [Dr. Midnight at Microsoft Answers](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-start-winpc/windows-10-taskbar-always-on-top-would-like-to/a39fe424-44f1-457e-8669-9f9f33e9e7e7) for this solution.

EDIT: This doesn't seem to work permanently. The problem has reappeared. I tried the same solution again, but this time it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix it by restarting explorer.exe with Task Manager.

Comment: The author indicated 3 years ago that they reboot their machine daily.  The author indicated in a comment 3 years ago that the daily reboot did not solve their problem.  That means that restarting explorer would not resolve their problem.  Since this question is nearly 3 years old, and the amount of information provided by the author is limited, it's unlikely an actual answer can be written.

Answer (score 0):

Weirdly, this solution works: On the affected screen put Chrome in full screen mode with F11, then back out of full screen mode with F11 again. Voila!, now the taskbar will be back on top.